# php+nginx+vagrant - php fails to write

Tags: php, linux, nginx, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a vagrant box setup running my dev code which is a nginx/php setup.
(Quick info on vagrant - its a virtualbox wrapper: http://www.vagrantup.com/).

In the vagrant/virtualbox setup, it is using linux guest additions to mount a shared folder on my host computer (MAC OSX).

```
linux guest path: /var/www/local 
OSX host path: ~/src/
```

On multiple occasions, I find that php can't seem to write anything through any command (`file_put_contents`, `fwrite`.. etc) to any path location on the mounted shared folder, However it is able to write outside of the `/var/www/local` (for example `/var/www/not-mounted/..`).

I find this very difficult to work with, as I am using a cache system and it keeps failing to write any of the cache javascript/css files to `(/var/www/local/public/root/cache/)` which I need to be in the root folder of my website which is (`/var/www/local/public/root/index.php`).

I have done a lot of research on this topic:
it seems, the folder mount has the right permissions:
When I type `mount` command in the linux guest, I get this:

```
/var/www/local on /var/www/local/ type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=1000,rw)
```

Clarify:

This happens all the time, it is a known problem I encounter which I try to workaround.

From `cat /etc/passwd`:

```
vagrant:x:1000:1000:vagrant,,,:/home/vagrant:/bin/bash
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It's not really clear if this happens sometimes or always. Either way it's important to know what the uid of the webserver is.

Comment: @Melvyn I will clarify: This happens all the time, it is a known problem I encounter which I try to workaround. 
From cat/etc/passwd: vagrant:x:1000:1000:vagrant,,,:/home/vagrant:/bin/bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem.

I have forgot to give PHP the correct user-privileges and permissions to write to the folder. Basically, my PHP user/user-group was www-data/www-data however, vagrant has its own user/group (vagrant/vagrant) which mounts the folder /local/.

Since I did not want to mess with my vagrant mounting behaviour, I just simply changed my php config to start PHP with the user/group - vagrant/vagrant.

This fixed the issue for me.

Thanks for the help!